# Libgdx isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.UP) does not work and keys do not map correctly

Tags: android, libgdx

I am working on a project (Mario remake) in Android Studio (on my laptop) and am using LibGDX. I am currently struggling on trying to make Mario move in this tutorial that I have been following. So I have done a bit of debugging on Android Studio and for whatever reason this never runs:

```
if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.UP)) {
    Gdx.app.log("Debug", "UP is pressed");
    player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 4f), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
}
```

The log is never printed to logcat when UP is pressed.

From what I can find, a lot of people have had problems with this function, and I can not find a way to get it to work. Some forums have even said that this function is broken. If that is the case, does anyone know of an alternative way to code this? Or is there something I am doing wrong/have not found out about with this function?

Additionally, LibGDX does not properly read the keys from my keyboard. From using a similar function `isKeyPressed()`, when I type in (for example) UP I have to press the right arrow key to go up in the game. Is there a fix for this or do I just have to settle with a poor mapping of the keys from LibGDX?

For more context, the keys that I am pressing to control Mario are from the keyboard on my laptop. The game is running on an AVD.

Additionally this is in my `handleInput()` function (where `isKeyJustPressed()` is being called):

```
public void handleInput(float dt) {
        // down is mapped to my right arrow key
        // up is mapped to my left arrow key
        // left is mapped to my up arrow key
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) {
            Gdx.app.log("Debug", "W is pressed");
            player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 4f), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN) && player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 2) {
            Gdx.app.log("Debug", "R is pressed");
            player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.1f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP) && player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x >= -2) {
            Gdx.app.log("Debug", "L is pressed");
            player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-0.1f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
        }
    }
```

This highlights how my keys are mismatched in order to get Mario moving. Additionally, the only first function does not work. Are these functions supposed to be meant for the keyboard on the android device?

More information:
`handleInput()` is called in `update()`
`update` is called in `render`
Each of these three functions takes in a float deltatime

I am running Android Studio version 3.6.3 and build number AI- 192.7142.36.36.6392135.

Let me know if anything else would be useful to provide for this question. Thanks!

Comment: this function works well in my projects... I noticed you said in your log cat, are you running this on android? how you gonna press the up button if your on a android? do you have a keyboard connected to your phone? also where is located this if statement? in the render method?

Comment: Add more code where you calling this function and what about Android studio its desktop or not?

Comment: Which platform are you using? If you are on Android, try using 1.9.11-SNAPSHOT